# if statement not working as expected in rails

Tags: ruby

i have this

```
    if ('row[4] ILIKE ? ', "google.co.uk")
```

However

I get this come in my console

```
SyntaxError: /Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/lib/tasks/ticketmaster.rake:18: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
        if ('row[4] ILIKE ? ',"google.co.......
```

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: `ILIKE` is a SQL keyword, not Ruby...

Answer (score 1):

There is no condition in your `if` statement.

A general `if` statement in Ruby will be like:

```
if a == 4 then a = 7 end
```

or:

```
if condition
  #do something
else
  #do something
end
```

whereas your code:

```
if ('row[4] ILIKE ? ', "google.co.uk")
```

does not seem to be a valid `if` statement.

See: "[Ruby Programming/Syntax/Control Structures](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Control_Structures)"

Comment: Need more context, from your code, like post the code before the if statement , and explain what you intent to do by implementing this condition, will be helpful to identify the issue

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to:

```
if row[4]=="google.co.uk"
// write your logic here
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO isn't a discussion board. Answers are for solutions. If you need a response from the OP to a question then add a comment to their question, not a question in the answer itself. When answering you should explain why this answer is appropriate. Educate how to do something, don't just toss out an answer.